# How to show dynamic maps in PDF using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wicked-pdf

I want to show world region wise map inside my PDF document. I had generated map using some jquery library but not bale to export same map inside PDF document generated through wicked_pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that works for me (you can attach ?d=1 see HTML version of PDF):

```
def index
  render :pdf => "pdf_with_map",
         :disposition => "attachment",
         :show_as_html => (params[:d] == "1"),
         :layout => "pdf",
         :orientation => 'Landscape'
end
```

And here is pdf layout:

```
!!!
%html
  %head{:xmlns => 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', :lang => 'en', 'xml:lang' => 'en'}
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}
    %title PDF
    = wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'pdf'
    = wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'jquery', 'jquery-jvectormap', 'jquery-jvectormap-world-en', 'regionVectorMap'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    #content
      = yield
```

When you use debug you will see that the helpers are embeding JavasSript into HTML. Map **did not work for me if jquery was in gem**, I moved jquery into my app/assets and so that the wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag can find the source ;-)